# Static property Intercept in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I am creating a configuration class in groovy as below

```
class EnvironmentConfig {
    String configFilePath
    Config envConfig

    public EnvironmentConfig (String configFilePath) {
        this.configFilePath = configFilePath
        envConfig = ConfigFactory.load(configFilePath)
    }

    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        envConfig.getString(name)
    }
}
```

The idea is that this class should be instantiated only once when my application comes up, and every other class should be able to access this class. Now I have written a very small main class to check something.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EnvironmentConfig envConfig = new EnvironmentConfig(envConf)
    println "${envConfig.TESS_WORKDIR}"
}
```

This works fine, however if I write like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EnvironmentConfig envConfig = new EnvironmentConfig(envConf)
    println "${EnvironmentConfig.TESS_WORKDIR}"
}
```

It does not works, I want that any class should be able to just use `EnvironmentConfig.TESS_WORKDIR` and call should be routed to the `missingProperty` method where it should return some value.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the following code does the job, didn't test it extensively:

```
class EnvironmentConfig {
   Map m

   EnvironmentConfig (Map m) {
      this.m = m
      this.class.metaClass.static.propertyMissing = { name ->
         this.propertyMissing(name)
      }
   }

   def propertyMissing(String name) {
      this.@m[name]
   }
}

EnvironmentConfig envConfig = new EnvironmentConfig([TESS_WORKDIR:1])
assert envConfig.TESS_WORKDIR == 1
assert EnvironmentConfig.TESS_WORKDIR == 1
envConfig = new EnvironmentConfig([:])
assert envConfig.TESS_WORKDIR == null
assert EnvironmentConfig.TESS_WORKDIR == null
```

Comment: @AmbujJauhari, if my answer helped you, please upvote and accept it.